# Chromadepth glasses

Tags: optics, visible-light, vision

I am making some 3D graphics in POV-Ray that are meant to be viewed using Chromadepth 3D glasses. These glasses make blue objects in a drawing look distant, and red objects look like they're close to the viewer. All other hues lie in between the minimum and maximum according to their place in the spectrum. (E.g. green is in the middle.)

http://chromatek.com/

Here is what I am working on right now.

[image]

My question is, is the 3D effect of the glasses supposed to be linear over distance in the image, or is the effect meant to be nonlinear and stronger at short/near distances than long/far distances? E.g.

Is the effect equivalent to

`hue = distance from camera`

or

`hue = arctan(distance from camera)`

Here is the patent:

https://www.google.com/patents/US5002364?hl=en

According to it, the glasses use some sort of fresnel lens or prisms to bend light based on wavelength. But I don't understand it that well.

Depending on the answer, I will have to update the above image.

[edit]

I found some OpenGL shader code [here](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~mjb/chromadepth/), but I'm not confident the author of this code really knows the answer to this question for sure (or cares), either.

Comment: It seems that a simple linear ramp is used, but that's not very satisfactory on tricolour monitors, since the amount of shifting depends on wavelength, not on perceived hue. But this article could be useful https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2630398

Comment: Interesting. They propose an alternate algorithm as opposed to mapping distance to hue linearly. I will probably purchase a copy of the PDF.